# Find the mass of a sphere with density given by $\rho(r,\theta,\phi)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The density is given by $$\rho=\rho_0e^{-r/R}(1-\cos\theta)$$
Where $R$ is the radius of the sphere.

I integrate as follows:

So, first integration is
$$\int_0^R \rho_0 e^{-\frac{r}{R}} (1-\cos  \theta ) r^2 (\sin  \theta ) \, dr=-\frac{(2 e-5) R^3 (\theta  \sin ) (\theta  \cos -1)}{e}$$
Second integration:
$$\rho_0\cdot\int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{(2 e-5) R^3 (\sin  \theta ) (\cos  \theta -1)}{e} \, d\theta$$ which is equal to zero, because I get in the indefenite integral the term $  \cos\theta -\frac{1}{4} (2 \theta )$, and when calculating it sums to $0$.

So, what is the mass of my sphere?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_\phi \int_\theta \int_r \mathrm{e}^{-r/R} (1-\cos \theta) r^2\sin \theta dr d\theta d\phi
$$

lets clean up a few things
$$
\dfrac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha r} = r^2\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha r}\\
\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\left(-\cos \theta -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \theta \right) = (1-\cos \theta )\sin \theta
$$
where $\alpha  = 1/R$
thus
we can 
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^R \left(R^2\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}\mathrm{e}^{-r/R} \right)\left(\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\left(-\cos \theta -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \theta \right) \right)dr d\theta d\phi =\\
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^R \left(R^2\dfrac{d^2}{dr^2}\mathrm{e}^{-r/R} \right)\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\left(-\cos \theta -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \theta \right) \right)dr d\theta d\phi
$$
i.e. over the first quadrant.
The $\theta$ integral is
$$
\left[-\cos \theta -\frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \theta \right]_{0}^{\pi/2} = 0 -(-1-1/2) = \frac{3}{2}
$$
then over $r$ it is
$$
\dfrac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\left[-\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha r}\right]_0^R\\
=\dfrac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)\\
= \frac{2}{\alpha^3}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right) = 2R^3\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)
$$
all together with the $\phi$ integral we obtain
$$
V_{1/8} = \frac{\pi}{2}2R^3\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)\frac{3}{2} = \frac{3\pi R^3}{2}\left(1-\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)
$$
so I get for your mass
$$
m = \frac{12\pi R^3\left(\mathrm{e}-1\right)}{\mathrm{e}}\rho_0
$$
?